# SQL Server job: FTP can't find file

Tags: sql-server, ftp, sql-job

I have created new job with 3 steps, Step 1: Creates FTP script, Step 2: runs FTP script and Step 3: delete FTP script. Step1 creates following script in c:\temp folder.

```
open myftplocation
userid
pwd
cd ..
cd destination
ascii
put c:\mylocalfilelocation\files\todaysfile.txt newfile.txt
quit
```

Step 2: 
ftp.exe -i -s:C:\temp\MyFTPscript.vbs

When it hits step 2, status shows successful but when I check detail message (In Job History) it says   ftp> put c:\mylocalfilelocation\files\todaysfile.txt newfile.txt c:\mylocalfilelocation\files\todaysfile.txt: File not found

I tried each command line by line on command prompt it works fine. Any idea what is messing up?

Thanks.

Comment: It can't find the file that you want to FTP i.e. c:\mylocalfilelocation\files\todaysfile.txt. Are you sure it exists?

Comment: What happens if you start the job manually?

Comment: Permissions. When the job goes to run the FTP command, can the login running the command access the directory and see the file?  You could verify that the directory is visible by trying to SEND a local file into the directory that you will be getting your source from..

Comment: @Steve Yes File exists

Comment: @Wlofgang When I double click batch file, it does not give any error and transfer the file

Comment: @Vergil I just listed FTP steps here, but before that the job creates todaysfie.txt so I believe whichever service account run this job has access to the file.

Comment: @Vergil - I rechecked account running the job and found it was running under different account - I changed it with desired account and it worked :) Thanks for the solution.